# Open API schema conditional response field based on the presence of a query parameter

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator, fastify

I am working on providing a GET REST API where I would like to conditionally include the total_documents field (its an integer count of the total number of records present in the DB table).

The API signature and response payload will be something like:

```
    GET /endpoint/?total_documents&.....

    Response Payload:
    {
         documents: [....],
         total_documents: 100
    }
```

Now I would like the total_documents field to be appeared in the response payload if and only if the total_documents query parameter exists in the URL.

This is what I tried, based on my schema:

```
 fastify.addSchema({
        $id: 'persistence-query-params',
        title: "PersistenceQueryParams",
        type: 'object',
        description: 'Persistence Service GET API URL query specification. Applicable for GET API only.',
        properties: {
            'total_documents': {
                description: 'Total number of documents present in the collection, after applying filters, if any. This query paramater does not take any value, just pass it as the name (e.g. &total_documents).',
                nullable: true,
            },
        },       
}
```

```
querystring: {
                description: 'Persistence Service GET API URL query specification. Applicable for GET API only.',
                $ref: 'persistence-query-params#',
            },
            response: {
                200: {
                    properties: {
                        'documents': {
                            description: 'All the retrieved document(s) from the specified collection for the specified service database and account.',
                            type: 'array',
                            items: {
                                $ref: 'persistence-response-doc#',                  
                            }
                        },
                        'total_documents': {
                            description: "If total_documents query paremeter is specified, gives the total number of documents present in the collection, after applying query paramaters, if any. If total_documents is not specified, this field will not be available in the response payload.",
                            type: 'number',
                            default: -1,
                        },
                    },
                    dependencies: {
                      'total_documents': { required: ['querystring/properties/total_documents'] },
                    },
                },
                '4xx': {
                    $ref: 'error-response#',
                    description: 'Error response.'
                }
            }
```

What is the way out here?

Thanks,
Pradip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON Schema has no notion of a request or response or HTTP.

What you have here is an OpenAPI specification document.

The OpenAPI specification defines a way to access dynamic values, but only within Link Objects or Callback Objects, which includes the query params.

> Runtime expressions allow defining values based on information that
> will only be available within the HTTP message in an actual API call.
> This mechanism is used by Link Objects and Callback Objects.

https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.1.0#runtime-expressions

JSON Schem has no way to reference instance data, let alone data relating to contexts it is unaware of.